# Playwright waitFor Vue is done with update

Tags: vue.js, playwright-test

One of my Vue components is supposed to render a pretty huge hierarchical data structure. I've to admit there might be room for improvement in terms of performance of this particular component (lazy loaded data, transforming into an internal UI Model with some refs and depending computeds). It takes up to a second until Vue / the component is done updateing.

Anyway we have some E2E Tests in place with playwright which work just fine in almost all places. As you might already expect we have a problem with this lazy loading inefficient component mentioned before.

```js
test('Modifications can be persisted and reloaded', async ({page}) => { 

    // .. doing something like editing, saving

    // refreshing to check the mutated model loads fine
    await page.reload();
    await page.waitForTimeout(2000);

    // check the value of an inputField which should be set by the internal model
    const statusValue = await page.getByLabel('Status').inputValue();
    expect(statusValue).toBe("Modified");           // fails with Value ""

});
```

The code above is a reduced version of the failing test. It fails sometimes on the line with `expect(statusValue)` because the inputValue() is empty. As a workaround I added `await page.waitForTimeout(2000);`. :-(

How would I wait for Vue being done with the update (waiting for "updated" Events)? Is there something like `waitUntilVueIsDone()`?

Are there any best practices on how to test lazy loaded data visualisations?

Comment: Wait for a specific element to appear. Since you test a component, it could be its selector, or root comp selector at least

Comment: @EstusFlask I thought that's what `getByLabel` is doing. Isn't it supposed to wait until the element appears? In this case the element is already visible. Just the content is appearing late because the data is loaded lazy. That's why `await page.getByLabel('Status').inputValue()` returns "" sometimes. Any idea on how to wait for a apecific inputText to appear?

Comment: The way it behaves is documented, https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about#types-of-queries . You could possibly increase a timeout, but then it would stall on failed queries. It's better to use waitFor with an element that's guaranteed to exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it turned out that it hasn't been an issue with Vue at all. We solved the problem by rewriting the test to utilize `expect` like this:

```
await expect(page.getByLabel('Status')).toHaveValue("Modified");
```

The key is [expect](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-assertions) automaticly retests until the assertion matches while [inputValue](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-input-value) does not.

Answer (score 0):

#### Separate the delayed and target element:

In most of these kind of scenarios , try waiting for the delayed selector(the one which signifies the state after complete re-loading) and then clicking the target element:

```
await this.page.waitForSelector('delayed element');
await this.page.click('target element'); //any operation on target element
```